# how to implement snappuzzle jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm quite new to javascript & jquery and wanted to use the snappuzzle plugin:
[snappuzzle plugin](https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/snap-puzzle/demo.html)
I thought that i should just download & link in my html-file to jquery, jquery ui & the snappuzle.js, as well as link to a code.js file where i put the `$(document).ready()(`

But somehow I can't seem to figure out what to do exactly to implement this plugin - both in my html as well as what i should do with the javascript

Can anyone help me?

Edit: Do you know if it's possible to change the background/template picture of the puzzle? As in, I would like to use another picture as the source of the template than the puzzle itself. I can't seem to find the code that does that..

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
});
```

```css
 body {
   font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    background: #ee9ca7; /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #ee9ca7 , #ffdde1); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #ee9ca7 , #ffdde1); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */      
 }
 
 * {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }
 
 .ref_imgWrap {
   max-width: 200px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin-top: 1em;
   position: relative;
 }
 
 .ref_imgWrap img {
   max-width: 100%;
   float: left;
   height: auto;
 }
 
 .contRofl_clr,
 .wrap {
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
 }
 
 .restartPuzzleWrap {
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 1em 0;
 }
 
 .restart_puzzleX999 {
   padding: 1.6em;
   display: inline-block;
   background: orange;
   color: #ffffff;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
   font-weight: 300;
   border-radius: 2px;
   cursor: pointer;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.35);
    -moz-box-shadow:    1px 1px 6px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.35);
    box-shadow:         1px 1px 6px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.35);
 }

.snappuzzle-piece {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.35);
    -moz-box-shadow:    1px 1px 6px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.35);
    box-shadow:         1px 1px 6px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.35);  
}
 /* required snapPuzzle styles */
 
 .puzzleX999_paddedWrap {
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
 
 .puzzleX999_imgWrap {
   max-width: 560px;
   padding: 5%;
   padding-top: 0;
   margin: 0 auto;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   position: relative;
 }
 
 .puzzleX999_imgWrap img {
   max-width: 100%;
   float: left;
   height: auto;
 }
 
 .puzzleX999_relWrap {
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   max-width: 500px;
   float: left;
 }
 
 #puzzleX999_Main {
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
 }
 
 .snappuzzle-wrap {
   position: relative;
   display: block;
 }
 /*snappuzzle-pile { position: relative; }*/
 
 .snappuzzle-piece {
   cursor: move;
 }
 
 .snappuzzle-slot {
   position: absolute;
   background: #fff;
   opacity: .8;
 }
 
 .snappuzzle-slot-hover {
   background: #eee;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head>

<title>Test puzzle</title>

<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="style.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>

<script src="code.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
<script src="jQuery-snapPuzzle.js"></script>

<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-throttle-debounce/1.1/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js'></script>




</head>
<body>

<div class="contRofl_clr">
      <div class="ref_imgWrap">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1462524500090-89443873e2b4?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=991&h=661&q=80" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="restartPuzzleWrap">
          <span class="restart_puzzleX999">
              Restart Puzzle
          </span>
      </div>
</div>


<div class="puzzleX999_paddedWrap">
   <div class="puzzleX999_imgWrap">
       <img class="puzzleX999_img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1462524500090-89443873e2b4?dpr=1&auto=compress,format&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=991&h=661&q=80" alt="" />
       <div id="puzzleX999_Main">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this an answer, or just the code you've tried? If the latter, please edit into your question.